# How can I convert a numerical solution to an analytical one?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, symbolic, nonlinear

```
Clear["`.*"]
e = 0.92; sm = 15.; phi = 1.122; sii = ArcCos[e Cos[phi]];
NDSolve[
  {SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]], PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e, 
   Y'[s] == Sin[PH[s]], X'[s] == Cos[PH[s]], PH[0] == phi, 
   SI[0] == sii, Y[0] == 0, X[0] == 0 }, 
  {SI, PH, Y, X}, {s, 0, sm}];
{si[u_], ph[u_], x[u_], y[u_]} = {SI[u], PH[u], X[u], Y[u]} /. First[%];
ParametricPlot[{x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, sm}]
```

After a numerical solution is obtained as above, how can I convert it to an analytic solution?

EDIT1:

$$ \frac{\cos \psi}{\cos \phi } = e= \frac{\sin \psi\,\cdot \psi^{'}}{\sin \phi \,\cdot\phi^{'} }; $$

$$ \psi^{'} =\sin \phi, \quad \phi^{'} = \sin \psi /e ;$$

[image: Conics_DEto Analyt_Soln]

Conics tangent/directrix/eccentricity property above is used to set up first degree differential equations aimed to seek analytic solution from numerical (when axes parallel to coordinate axes) in the plane using *Mathematica*.

Comment: If I understand right, you cannot compute an exact solution from an approximate one.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Your plotted solution looks like an ellipse.  Try fitting it to one.

Comment: `DSolve[{SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] , PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e}, {SI[s], PH[s]}, s]` yields a symbolic solution, although not a very convenient one.

Comment: Also, `Cos[SI[s]] == -C[1] + e Cos[PH[s]]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey. Thanks. That is what I started with. How do we get it, using Reduce? If so  cannot $X,Y $ be also next found by integrating elliptic integrals/functions ?

Comment: Remember that the symbolic solutions involving elliptic functions that we are discussing provide `s` as a function of `PH`, not the inverse.  Perhaps, it is possible also to obtain `X` and `Y` as solutions involving elliptic functions, but as functions of `PH`, not `s`.  The fundamental issue from my perspective is,  what precisely are you seeking.  To say that you want "an analytic solution" is not sufficient, unless you define precisely what you mean by "analytical".  Elliptic functions, for instance, are analytical, but are integrals of them, or their inverses?

Comment: I hoped to be able to obtain dependent variables  $PH,SI,X,Y$ of an ellipse like curve in terms of/ as a function of the chosen independent variable $s$, the arc length, to the extent possible as, only trg functions are involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Numerical Results**

The equations in the question can be solved symbolically, but in terms of `PH`, not `s`.  To begin, it is helpful to plot the numerical solution calculated in the question.

```
ParametricPlot[{x[s], y[s]}, {s, 0, sm}]
```

[image]

which is an ellipse.  Plotting numerical results for the four dependent variables as functions of `s` also is useful.

```
Plot[{si[s], x[s], y[s], ph[s]}, {s, 0, sm}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

`y[s]` does not look like `x[s]` rescaled by `e` and offset by a constant.

**Symbolic Solution**

```
Clear[e, phi]; sii = ArcCos[e Cos[phi]];
ds = DSolve[{SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] , PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e}, {SI[s], PH[s]}, s] // Last
(* {SI[s] -> ArcCos[-C[1] + e Cos[InverseFunction[-((4 I Cos[#1/2]^2 Sqrt[(
    1 + C[1] - e Cos[#1])/((1 - e + C[1]) (1 + Cos[#1]))]
    Sqrt[(1 - C[1] + e Cos[#1])/((1 + e - C[1]) (1 + Cos[#1]))] EllipticF[
    I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(1 + e + C[1])/(1 - e + C[1])] Tan[#1/2]], 
    (1 - 2 e + e^2 - C[1]^2)/(1 + 2 e + e^2 - C[1]^2)])/(
    Sqrt[(1 + e + C[1])/(2 - 2 e + 2 C[1])] Sqrt[
    2 - e^2 - 2 C[1]^2 + 4 e C[1] Cos[#1] - e^2 Cos[2 #1]])) &][s/e + C[2]]]], 
    PH[s] -> InverseFunction[-((4 I Cos[#1/2]^2 Sqrt[(
    1 + C[1] - e Cos[#1])/((1 - e + C[1]) (1 + Cos[#1]))] Sqrt[(
    1 - C[1] + e Cos[#1])/((1 + e - C[1]) (1 + Cos[#1]))] EllipticF[
    I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(1 + e + C[1])/(1 - e + C[1])] Tan[#1/2]], 
    (1 - 2 e + e^2 - C[1]^2)/(1 + 2 e + e^2 - C[1]^2)])/(
    Sqrt[(1 + e + C[1])/(2 - 2 e + 2 C[1])] Sqrt[
    2 - e^2 - 2 C[1]^2 + 4 e C[1] Cos[#1] - e^2 Cos[2 #1]])) &][s/e + C[2]]} *)
```

(`DSolve` yields another symbolic solution which can be obtained from the one above by replacing `s` by `-s` and `SI` by `-SI`.)  Now, determine the two constants of motion.

```
Flatten@Solve[Map[Cos, (First[ds] /. (Last[ds] /. Rule[z1_, z2_] -> Rule[z2, z1]))
    /. Rule -> Equal], C[1]]
(* {C[1] -> e Cos[PH[s]] - Cos[SI[s]]} *)
```

Applying the initial conditions from the question then gives

```
% /. s -> 0 /. { PH[0] -> phi, SI[0] -> sii}
(* {C[1] -> 0} *)
```

and, because `C[1]` vanishes, `Cos[SI[s]] == e Cos[PH[s]]`, as also is evident from

```
ds0 = ds /. % /. Function[z_] :> Function @@ {z}
(* {SI[s] -> ArcCos[e Cos[
    InverseFunction[-((4 I Cos[#1/2]^2 Sqrt[(1 - e Cos[#1])/((1 - e) (1 + Cos[#1]))]
    Sqrt[(1 + e Cos[#1])/((1 + e) (1 + Cos[#1]))] EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(1 + e)/(1 - e)]
    Tan[#1/2]], (1 - 2 e + e^2)/(1 + 2 e + e^2)])/(
    Sqrt[(1 + e)/(2 - 2 e)] Sqrt[2 - e^2 - e^2 Cos[2 #1]])) &][s/e + C[2]]]], 
    PH[s] -> 
    InverseFunction[-((4 I Cos[#1/2]^2 Sqrt[(1 - e Cos[#1])/((1 - e) (1 + Cos[#1]))]
    Sqrt[(1 + e Cos[#1])/((1 + e) (1 + Cos[#1]))] EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(1 + e)/(1 - e)]
    Tan[#1/2]], (1 - 2 e + e^2)/(1 + 2 e + e^2)])/(
    Sqrt[(1 + e)/(2 - 2 e)] Sqrt[2 - e^2 - e^2 Cos[2 #1]])) &][s/e + C[2]]]] *)
```

The symbolic expression and numerical value for `C[2]` are obtained simply by

```
PH[s] /. ds0 /. s -> 0;
FullSimplify[%[[0, 1]][phi], Pi/2 > phi > -Pi/2 && 1 > e > 0]
% /. {e -> 0.92 , phi -> 1.122} // Chop
(* -((2 I EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[-((1 + e)/(-1 + e))] Tan[phi/2]], 
    (-1 + e)^2/(1 + e)^2])/(1 + e)) *)
(* 1.91604 *)
```

To proceed, it convenient to determine `X` and `Y` in terms of `PH`, which is accomplished by transforming the independent variable in their ODEs to `PH` and employing `Integrate` to obtain solutions up to a constant.

```
xs = FullSimplify[Integrate[e Cos[PH]/Sqrt[1 - e^2 Cos[PH]^2], PH], 0 < e < 1]
(* ArcTanh[(Sqrt[2] e Sin[PH])/Sqrt[2 - e^2 - e^2 Cos[2 PH]]] *)

ys = Integrate[e Sin[PH]/Sqrt[1 - e^2 Cos[PH]^2], PH]
(* -ArcSin[e Cos[PH]] *)
```

These two expressions, plus `Cos[SI[s]] == e Cos[PH[s]]`, obtained earlier, give

```
Plot[{ArcCos[e Cos[PH] /. e -> 0.92], Evaluate[(xs - (xs /. PH -> ph[0])) /. e -> 0.92], 
    Evaluate[(ys - (ys /. PH -> ph[0])) /. e -> 0.92]}, {PH, ph[0], ph[sm]}]
```

[image]

This plot is identical to what can be obtained for the numerical solutions by

```
ParametricPlot[{{ph[s], si[s]}, {ph[s], x[s]}, {ph[s], y[s]}}, {s, 0, sm},
    PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Thus, `SI`, `X`, and `Y` have been obtained as symbolic functions of `PH`, and `PH` as a seemingly symbolic function of `s` in `ds0`.  Unfortunately, `InverseFunction` is not really symbolic, and moreover does not return numerical values for the full range of `s`.  So, the final step is to obtain `s` as a function of `PH`, which can be done by extracting the function inside `InverseFunction` and applying it to `PH`, yielding for `s`.

```
e ((PH[s] /. ds0)[[0, 1]][PH] - C[2])
(* e (-C[2] - (4 I Cos[PH/2]^2 Sqrt[(1 - e Cos[PH])/((1 - e) (1 + Cos[PH]))]
   Sqrt[(1 + e Cos[PH])/((1 + e) (1 + Cos[PH]))]
   EllipticF[I ArcSinh[Sqrt[(1 + e)/(1 - e)] Tan[PH/2]], (1 - 2 e + e^2)/
   (1 + 2 e + e^2)])/(Sqrt[(1 + e)/(2 - 2 e)] Sqrt[2 - e^2 - e^2 Cos[2 PH]])) *)
```

However, this expression is multivalued, so its period must be determined,

```
fun = % /. e -> .92 /. C[2] -> 1.9160429061618474`;
per = Re@N[fun /. PH -> Pi - 10^-7] - Re@N[fun /. PH -> Pi + 10^-7]
(* 8.7583 *)
```

Finally, this gives `s` vs `PH`.

```
ParametricPlot[{Piecewise[{{fun, PH < Pi}, {fun + per, PH < 3 Pi}, 
    {fun + 2 per, PH < 5 Pi}}], PH}, {PH, ph[0], ph[15]},
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

All four dependent functions now have been obtained parametrically in terms of `s`.  Although I undertook this solution as a challenge, realistically the numerical solution is more useful for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks soo much for the elaborate reply.. which serves  me  also as  tutorial with application to conics, It should be also of general interest. Shall edit question reg  conics  differential equation background.

Comment: [enter link description here][2]
  [2]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319252/how-to-parameterize-the-elliptic-equation-with-length-of-arc-t/2319409?noredirect=1#comment4773552_2319409 // Gave a link to a relevant question, hope OK,