# DSolve with SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce] Behaving Differently in Ver 11.1.1

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

With version "11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)",

```
DSolve[{SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] , PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e}, {SI[s], PH[s]}, s]
```

produces the common warning message,

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

and then a lengthy answer, the `Last` half of which is given in the [answer to 147688](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148146/1063), all in about 5 sec.  A [typical method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/1063) of employing `Reduce`, as the warning suggests, is

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
```

However, `DSolve` appears to ignore this setting, returning the same warning message and answer in the same amount of time.

With version "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)", and the default `Method` for `Solve`, `DSolve` again produces the same warning message and answer in the same amount of time.  In contrast, with `Method -> Reduce` `DSolve` runs about 250 sec before returning unevaluated.

Question - How is this difference to be interpreted?  Possibilities that come to mind include:

1. Version 11.1.1 of `DSolve` immediately recognizes that `Reduce` cannot produce an answer and ignores the instruction to use it.
2. Version 11.1.1 contains a bug, albeit fortuitous in this case.
3. There is a new way to invoke `Reduce` with `DSolve`, and I am the last to know it.

By the way, this is not the first instance in which I have seen `DSolve` ver 11.1.1 ignore `Method -> Reduce`.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143422/4999 for some info.  See if it answers your Q.  Basically, V11, `DSolve` calls `Solve` with a specialized `Method`; so you cannot override it with `SetOptions` anymore.

Comment: Actually, in this case, it seems to be calling `Solve` with `Method -> "Algebraic"`.  (I do not know what these undocumented methods do, nor how many there are.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Very helpful (+1).  How did you find this information?  `Trace` with `TraceInternal -> True`?  Unfortunately, `DSolve` with `Method -> Reduce` in your code returns unevaluated, as it did in Ver 10.4.1.  I see that I really need to learn about `Internal``InheritedBlock`.  What is the best source of information?  Thanks.

Comment: I put a `Print[{opts}]` statement, among other such debugging statements, in the redefined `Solve` in my linked answer. The ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` approach allows much more targeted responses to different conditions.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I found your comments very useful, and I imagine that others will too.  May I suggest, therefore, that you convert them into an answer to my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Introduction

I will discuss the issues that lead to the inverse function message and a few debugging tools I used, which it might be well to have collected in one place for reference. Finally I will show how to use some of these tools on the OP's example.
In getting around the inverse function warning we are able to recover a branch winding number as a discrete parameter that is missed by the straight `DSolve` call.
With respect to the main point, the question itself about how to control the method used by `Solve` is addressed. In fact how to target the specific call to `Solve` that emits the `Solve::ifun` message is shown.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `DSolve` analyzes the differential equation for particular special types.  It is conceivable that a message might be generated in checking a submethod that is irrelevant (i.e. that would not solve it).  Fixing the error message would not help in such a case.

### Discussion of the problem

One can see (using techniques discussed in the following sections) that the offending equation seems quite simple:

```
Solve[-Cos[SI[PH]]==C[1]-e Cos[PH],SI[PH]]
```

If you try to solve it outright, there is no problem. You get the following with no error/warning messages:

```
{{SI[PH] ->
   ConditionalExpression[-ArcCos[-C[1] + e Cos[PH]] + 2 π C[2], C[2] ∈ Integers]},
 {SI[PH] ->
   ConditionalExpression[ArcCos[-C[1] + e Cos[PH]] + 2 π C[2], C[2] ∈ Integers]}}
```

Note the term `2 π C[2]`, where the integer parameter `C[2]` could be called a "winding number." It turns out that `DSolve[]` does two things that affect the ability of `Solve[]` to handle the equation.  It makes the following calls:

```
SetSystemOptions[ReduceOptions->UseTranscendentalSolve->False]
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> "Restricted"]
```

Note that the second one, `SetOptions[]`, is executed after `DSolve` starts and overrides the `SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduced]` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/accessing-reduce-from-dsolve/63676#63676).  On the other hand, it is `"ReduceOptions"` setting that leads to the `Solve::ifun` warning in the present case, which you can check with the following, with or without the `Method` setting:

```
With[{redopts = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "UseTranscendentalSolve" -> False],
  Solve[-Cos[SI[PH]] == C[1] - e Cos[PH], SI[PH](*, Method -> "Restricted"*)],
  SetSystemOptions[redopts]
  ]]
```

One thing to keep in mind is that automatic settings depend on heuristics, which are chosen to be helpful in most (but not always all) cases.
I suspect that solutions containing `ConditionalExpression` are more trouble than they are worth, especially ones depending on a new parameter like `C[2]`. Hence, the `"ReduceOptions"` setting used by `DSolve` leads to the solution in the example. Likewise, the undocumented `Method -> "Restricted"`, whatever it does, must remove or tweak cases that arise in the `Automatic` setting and are troublesome for `DSolve`.

### Some debugging tools

It may be of general interest and useful to collect some of the ways of investigating `DSolve`.  A few of these are undocumented but often found on this site.  Some of these techniques can be used with other solvers, too.  It seems almost obvious that a general solver `DSolve` might call other solvers like `Integrate` and `Solve`, and possibly others like `Reduce` (no) and `Simplify` (yes).  It is worth remarking that while it appears from the docs that `DSolve` does not use assumptions, some of these other functions do, `Integrate` and `Simplify` being noteworthy examples. However, it does reset `$Assumptions` before returning (as I discovered below).

**Tracing.**
There are [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)
and
[`On`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/On.html).
`On[Solve]` and `On[SetOptions]` yields information on calls to each function. `On[SetOptions]` generates quite a few calls.  A more targeted approach is to use `Trace` with patterns:

```
Trace[
  DSolve[{SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]], PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e}, {SI[s], PH[s]}, s],
  _Solve | SetOptions[Solve, _],
  TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten
```

**Trapping system function calls.**
`` Internal`InheritedBlock `` allows one to intercept system function calls, add definitions to them and print out or `Sow` information about the call.  The great thing here is that when it is done, the system function reverts to its old self, and you don't have to worry about forgetting to reset something.

**Villegas-Gayley.**
The Villegas-Gayley trick is the way to insert your own code between a system function call and the execution of the function.

```
f[args...] /; !TrueQ[someVariable] := Block[{someVariable = True},
  <your code here>;
  f[args]]
```

You have to get the new definition ahead of all others, and sometimes one has to do it explicitly by setting its [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

**Temporarily setting system options (or whatever).**
A typical `` Internal`WithLocalSettings `` usage has the form

```
With[{currentsettings = ...},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  <settings>,
  <code>,
  <reset currentsettings/cleanup>
 ]]
```

The `<settings>` is executed first, then `<code>`, then `<reset..>`.
The advantage here is that the reset happens even if the `<code>` is aborted (e.g., by the menu command Evaluation > Abort Evaluation).

### Intercepting `Solve[]` and solving the differential equation

This section serves two functions, to compute an enhanced solution and to show how to alter the options of `Solve` when called by `DSolve`.  We will use many of the things discussed above to reset `SystemOptions` and change the options passed to `Solve`.
In particular, [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html) is used to make an alternative call to `Solve` when the original call emits the `Solve:ifun` message.

In fact the alternate call to `Solve` returns conditional expressions, which `DSolve` did not handle successfully nor quickly.  So I thought to break it down and add the condition to `$Assumptions` and post-proces the result of `DSolve` to be a `ConditionalExpression` based on the conditions accumulated.  More importantly in this case, the conditions depend on a integer parameter that with the default settings is `C[2]`, the same as a continuous parameter used by `DSolve` in the general solution.  This conflict has to be resolved, which I did by manually setting the `GeneratedParameters` option in `Solve`.  Another potential bug is that independent calls to `Solve` might generate independent parameters with the same name.  While it in fact happens in this case, ignoring it turns out to be safe.  (It could be dealt with, but this example does not seem worth the trouble.)

A utility to add conditions to a `DSolve` solution:

```
(* convert a DSolve solution to a ConditionExpression *)
addConditions[conditions_] := {
   HoldPattern[var_ -> Function[x_, expr_]] :>
    var -> With[{cond = Simplify[And @@ Flatten@conditions]},
      Function @@ Hold[x, ConditionalExpression[expr, cond]]],
   HoldPattern[var_ -> expr_] :>
    var -> ConditionalExpression[expr, Simplify[And @@ Flatten@conditions]]};
```

The example intercept of `Solve` within `DSolve`:

```
On[$Assumptions];  (* shows when  $Assumptions  is changed *)
Module[{assum = True},
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve, $Assumptions},
  Unprotect[Solve];
  call : Solve[eq_, v_, opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] :=
   Block[{$in = True, $res1, $res2},
    Check[ (* Use Check to try default settings & respond to messages *)
     $res1 = call (* try original call *)
     , (* Check[] *)
     Print["Trying \"ReduceOptions\" -> \"UseTranscendentalSolve\" -> True on ",
      HoldForm[call]];
     With[{redopts = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]},
      Internal`WithLocalSettings[
       SetSystemOptions[
        "ReduceOptions" -> "UseTranscendentalSolve" -> True],           (* I`WLS: init *)
       $res2 = Solve[eq, v, GeneratedParameters -> $S, opts];
       $res2 = $res2 /. ConditionalExpression[e_, c_] :> (* map condition to assumption *)
          ($Assumptions = $Assumptions && c;             (* for solvers and Simplify[] *)
           assum = assum && c;                           (* for addConditions[] at end *)
           e);
       Print["$Assumptions now ", $Assumptions];  (* context for On[$Assumptions] *)
       $res2 = Simplify[$res2];
       Print["Result= ", $res2],
       SetSystemOptions[redopts]                                        (* I`WLS: reset *)
       ];
      ];
     If[FreeQ[$res2, Solve], $res2, $res1]
     , (* Check[] *)
     {Solve::ifun}]
    ];
  Protect[Solve];
  sol = DSolve[{SI'[s] == Sin[PH[s]], PH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/e}, {SI,
     PH}, s];
  Print["$Assumptions finally ", $Assumptions];    (* context for On[$Assumptions] *)
  sol = sol /. addConditions[assum]
  ]]
Off[$Assumptions];
```

`Message` and `Print` output (`Print` statements shown in italics):

> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> True`. ... (x3)
>
> `Solve::ifun`: Inverse functions are being used by `Solve`, so some
>   solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution
>   information.
>
> *Trying `"ReduceOptions" -> "UseTranscendentalSolve"->True` on `Solve[-Cos[SI[PH]]==C[1]-e Cos[PH],SI[PH]]`*
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> True`.
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> $S[1]∈Integers`.
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> $S[1]∈Integers &&
>   $S[1]∈Integers`.
>
> *`$Assumptions` now `$S[1]∈Integers && $S[1]∈Integers`*
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> $S[1]∈Integers &&
>   $S[1]∈Integers`.
>
> *Result= `{{SI[PH]->-ArcCos[-C[1]+e Cos[PH]]+2 π $S[1]},{SI[PH]->ArcCos[-C[1]+e Cos[PH]]+2 π $S[1]}}`*
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> $S[1]∈Integers &&
>   $S[1]∈Integers`.
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> True`.
>
> *`$Assumptions` finally `True`*
>
> `$Assumptions::trace: $Assumptions --> True`. ... (x4)

Output (abridged).  The `$S[1]` is the "winding number" parameter lost in the default `DSolve` by "Inverse functions...being used"; it appears only in `SI`.

```
{{SI -> Function[{s},
    ConditionalExpression[-ArcCos[ ..] + 2 π $S[1], $S[1] ∈ Integers]],
  PH -> Function[{s},
    ConditionalExpression[InverseFunction[.. &][-(s/e) + C[2]], $S[1] ∈ Integers]]},
 {SI -> Function[{s},
    ConditionalExpression[ArcCos[ ..] + 2 π $S[1], $S[1] ∈ Integers]],
  PH -> Function[{s},
    ConditionalExpression[InverseFunction[.. &][s/e + C[2]], $S[1] ∈ Integers]]}}
```

Example print statements and `Solve` commands that might be used to investigate :

```
(* Print statements *)
Print[HoldForm[call]];
Print["SystemOptions[\"ReduceOptions\"]= ", SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]];
Print["opts= ", {opts}];
Print["Trying Method -> Reduce on ", HoldForm[call],
  ", Options[Solve]= ", Options[Solve],
  ", SystemOptions[\"ReduceOptions\"]= ",
  SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]];
Print["Trying \"ReduceOptions\" -> \"UseTranscendentalSolve\" -> True on ",
 HoldForm[call]];
Print["Result= ", $res2];
Print@Stack[];

(* Alternative Solve[] ideas *)
Solve[eq, v, GeneratedParameters -> $S, Method -> Reduce, opts]     (* Method -> Reduce *)
TimeConstrained[Solve[eq, v, GeneratedParameters -> $S, opts], 10]  (* abort long Solve *)
```

### References for undocumented features

Villegas-Gayley:
[What are some advanced uses for Block?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/what-are-some-advanced-uses-for-block/11585#11585),
[SO/4198961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656).

`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``:
[How safe is the use of Block and Internal`InheritedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25673/how-safe-is-the-use-of-block-and-internalinheritedblock/25934#25934)

`` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``:
[SO/7586735](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586735/how-to-catch-interrupts-generated-by-timeconstrained/7586910#7586910),
[How to flush machine underflows to zero and prevent conversion to arbitrary precision?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/how-to-flush-machine-underflows-to-zero-and-prevent-conversion-to-arbitrary-prec/25668#25668)

Comment: Superb!  Thank you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You're welcome.