# Differential equation, Inverse Functions being used and a way to bypass it.

Tags: differential-equations, trigonometry

I have the following differential equation

```
DSolve[(Sin[c1]^2 Sin[c2] Sin[
    q[z]]^2 (3 Cos[q[z]] (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2) + 
     z Sin[q[z]] (3 Derivative[1][q][z] + 
        4 z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^3 - z (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z])))/(
  z^5 (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2)^(3/2)) == 0, q[z], z]
```

And I would like Mathematica to solve it for me.

I know that the solution to the above is $ArcCos(m z)$.

To make it explicit.

```
In[102]:= (
   Sin[c1]^2 Sin[c2] Sin[
     q[z]]^2 (3 Cos[q[z]] (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2) + 
      z Sin[q[z]] (3 Derivative[1][q][z] + 
         4 z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^3 - z (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z])))/(
   z^5 (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2)^(3/2)) == 0 /. 
  q -> (ArcCos[m #] &) // Factor

Out[102]= True
```

I understand that DSolve has difficulties when I input that particular D.E, so I was wondering if there is any way to go about it.

The message that I am getting is

Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

But I don't understand how I could help Mathematica using the Reduce function. The DSolve command

```
DSolve[(Sin[c1]^2 Sin[c2] Sin[
    q[z]]^2 (3 Cos[q[z]] (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2) + 
     z Sin[q[z]] (3 Derivative[1][q][z] + 
        4 z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^3 - z (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z])))/(
  z^5 (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2)^(3/2)) == 0, q[z], z]
```

and the result

```
During evaluation of In[104]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

During evaluation of In[104]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Out[104]= DSolve[(
  Sin[c1]^2 Sin[c2] Sin[
    q[z]]^2 (3 Cos[q[z]] (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2) + 
     z Sin[q[z]] (3 Derivative[1][q][z] + 
        4 z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^3 - z (q^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z])))/(
  z^5 (1 + z^2 Derivative[1][q][z]^2)^(3/2)) == 0, q[z], z]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699)?

Comment: Thank you very much. No I hadn't seen that. There are some interesting approaches there. I will try these things, and if I get it to work I will update here with the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148226/1063) also may be useful.  (If it is, please up-vote the answer, which I think  is extraordinary.)

Comment: The answer is indeed extraordinary and thanks for pointing this out, but I haven't made it to work for my example. I gave an upvote however as the answer is really good.